# Python XGBoost Generate Prediction Mathematical Equation

Tags: python, math, data-science, xgboost

I have a XGBRegressor model and now I'm curious if there is a way to generate the final prediction equation in Python.

P.S: I do not have mathematical background so if my question is considered basic, please understand.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the problem, the final 'equation' could be arbitrarily complex.

A good place to start is to inspect one or some of the decision trees:

from xgboost import plot_tree

Which takes your trained model and the tree index as arguments.

Comment: Yes I already have the tree. It has the leaf score. But I don't understand how the score is used to calculate the prediction. So just to be safe and not misunderstand how it works, I want to know how the model calculate the prediction and I will work from there.